# Short phrase meaning "Area of study, activity, or interest where a particular technology or method is used."

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I feel like I know a phrase like [...] of [...] that is often used on the tip of my tongue, but can't spit it out.

Comment: What does "area of study" lack that you need the phrase to have?

Comment: I'd like to phrase to be more agnostic to whether it is study, activity, or interest. Kind of like wheelhouse, but for the applicability of a technology or method, not a person's skill.

Comment: Hey @Astralbee--"Discipline" I think is getting pretty close. Maybe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Field of expertise
- Field of study
- Area of expertise

These are all interchangeable.

A similar question, albeit asking for a *single word* has been asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453754/a-single-word-for-field-of-interest). Answers included the words "discipline", "subject", "specialty" and, most interesting, the borrow word "métier".

Comment: See my comment above responding to @KillingTime. I'd like it to be general enough to be any of those.